# Laplace transform of $\frac{1}{t^{2}}$

Tags: laplace-transform

I need to find the Laplace transform of $\frac{1}{t^{2}}$

Does the laplace transform of $\frac{1}{t^{2}}$ exist? If yes, how do we calculate it? Putting it in won't solve.

I'm not understanding in the replacement part, should I do u = -st or u = t?

$\frac{1}{s}\int_0^{s} \frac{e^{-u}}{u^2}du$?

Suggestion: $\int_0^{1} e^{-st}\frac{1}{t^{2}}$ + $ \int_1^{\infty} e^{-st}\frac{1}{t^{2}}$

Comment: Does not exist.

Comment: Doesn't exist because $\frac{1}{t^{2}}$ is not of exponential order. This means when t gets closer and closer to 0 there's no exponential function that grows faster (and this way the integral will diverge). Therefore, due $\frac{1}{t^{2}}$ doesn't satisfy the necessary condition of existence of Laplace transform of a function, it will not exist.

Comment: @ppmbb could you show how the integrations would be? I'm not understanding in the replacement part, should I do u = -st or u = t?

Comment: Before jumping into integrating you have to verify (or know beforehand) that your function $f(t)$ is of exponential order, this means, to check if there exist positive constants $\alpha$ and $M$ such that $|f(t)| \leq M e^{\alpha t}$. But when $t$ tend to zero, your function tends indefinitely to $\infty$. So there are no such constants to satisfy the inequality. Therefore there's no convergence for the integral, and no Laplace transform exists.

Comment: understanding of the tissue condition. however, unfortunately, my professor expects me to describe the calculations step by step. but I don't understand the variable change resolution.

Comment: I see, $u=st$ should do the trick then.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick answer (be aware about my lack of rigor).

By taking $u=st$:

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{t^2}e^{-st} dt = s \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-u}}{u^2}du \geq s \int_0^{1} \frac{e^{-u}}{u^2}du\geq s\int_0^{1} \frac{e^{-1}}{u^2}du = se^{-1} \left[ \frac{-1}{u} \right]_0^1$$
and the right side evaluation doesn't exist for $u=0$. Therefore the integral does not converge.

Comment: $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{t^2}e^{-st} dt = s \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-u}}{u^2}du $
I can't understand this part:
if u = st, why u²?

Comment: if $u=st$ then $\frac{1}{t^2} = \frac{s^2}{u^2}$ and $du=s dt$ then $dt = \frac{du}{s}$

Comment: thank you very much, I understood the variable change of this question